# problem to deserialize array data on typescript (React-native)

Tags: typescript, parsing

i need to parse my data array to myModel[].

this is data load:

```
    export function getMockFAQ() {
return [
    {
        title: "FAQ Question 1"
    },
    {
        title: "FAQ Question 1"
    },
    {
        title: "FAQ Question 1"
    }
]
}
```

my model:

```
export interface FAQInterface {
title: string;
}
```

how can i convert this data to FAQInterface[] ?

```
const data = getMockFAQ();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So easy kkkkkk

```
  export function getMockFAQ(): FAQInterface[] {
return [
{
    title: "FAQ Question 1"
},
{
    title: "FAQ Question 1"
},
{
    title: "FAQ Question 1"
}
]
}
```